# awk command to match multiple patterns

Tags: bash, awk

I am using an awk command to find entries in my log file between two different times.
I have used this command, and it works:

```
awk '$0 >= "Oct 04 12:00:00" && $0 <= "Oct 04 12:30:00"' /var/log/messages
```

I want to know how I can search for a specific port that was allowed or blocked during this time. For example: if I am searching for port 22 blocked between 12:00 to 12:30, how can I search it using this awk command?

Content of `/var/log/messages` file:

```
Nov 5 8:44:30 System1 Kernel [022525 252748] OUTPUT DROPPED=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:01:00:25:97:b2:47:01:00 SRC=10.0.0.1 DST=192.168.4.141 LEN=221 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=23315 PROTO=UDP SPT=183 DPT=183 LEN=209
```

The entries in the log file look similar to something like above. I want to know how can I match information between, let's say, 12:00 to 12:30 where SPT=80 and DPT=80

Comment: We don't know how your log file looks like.  What specific keywords will be there? The structure of the log file might be useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can add more conditions with `&&` just like you are doing with the dates. You can put a regular expression between two forward slashes to match against the whole line/record.

```
awk '/port 22 (blocked|allowed)/ && $0 >= "Oct 04 12:00:00" && $0 <= "Oct 04 12:30:00"' /var/log/messages
```

Of course you can also use parentheses and combinations of logical and (`&&`) and/or or (`||`) if you need more complex rules.

> I want to know how can I match information between, let's say, 12:00 to 12:30 where SPT=80 and DPT=80

Following the explanation above, simply add `/SPT=80/ && /DPT=80/ && ...` conditions. Note that the example line you showed won't match, as it has SPT and DPT values not 80 but 143.

And btw, keep in mind that the way you filter by date (for example `$0 >= "Oct 04 12:00:00" && $0 <= "Oct 04 12:30:00"`) may not work for dates crossing month boundaries, for example lower bound in `Nov` with a higher bound in `Dec` will not work.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am not looking for blocked or allowed option. It was only for example I gave. I am looking for source port which is SPT as shown in sample output in my question. So if I replace to `awk '/SPT=80/ && $0 >= "Oct 04 12:00:00" && $0 <= "Oct 04 12:30:00"' /var/log/messages` I get a blank line.

Comment: Giving as your example something you don't want to do is never a great idea vs just describing and showing what you do want to do.

Comment: @JoeWoods Well, since you didn't give your actual example, I answered what you asked. Anyway, the part with `/SPT=80/` is correct. Try with _only_ that (i.e., `awk '/SPT=80/' /var/log/messages`). If you then see the lines, you know it is the date filtering which you have wrong. Fix it.